# Multiple configuration json files using Host.CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, .net-6.0

In a console application, I'm using the following setup:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<Program>();
        string someConfigItem = context.Configuration["SomeConfigItem"];
    })
    .Build();

host.Services.GetRequiredService<Program>().Go();
```

This automatically reads from `appsettings.json` without having to explicitly use a configuration builder or anything like that.

What if I want to add an additional JSON file? With the configuration builder, you can just add multiple files by just calling `.AddJsonFile()` multiple times, but I can't seem to find a place to do add more files here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thing this is the right place to adding another configuration files:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

IHost host = Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x => x.AddJsonFile("..." /*..., ...*/))
    //.ConfigureHostConfiguration(x => x.AddJsonFile("..." /*..., ...*/))
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<Program>();
        string someConfigItem = context.Configuration["SomeConfigItem"];
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!